# include external header not working

Tags: php, html, include

I can't include external header .html with PHP 5.6 `<?php include ("Menu.html"); ?>` `
But in result the menu is never shown. Here is  [My full project](https://mega.nz/#F!KNd03bIC!JUMobEWn-af6dPwUGA8avA)

This the external Menu.html file (with header):

```html
<!-- Basic Page Needs
        ================================================== -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Dan Caldr">
<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
        ================================================== -->
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Template CSS Files
        ================================================== -->
<!-- Twitter Bootstrs CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons Fonts Css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- animate css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<!-- Hero area slider css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">
<!-- owl craousel css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
<!-- template main css file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<!-- responsive css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">

<!-- Template Javascript Files
        ================================================== -->
<!-- modernizr js -->
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- owl carouserl js -->
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap js -->

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- wow js -->
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<!-- slider js -->
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<!-- template main js -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<header id="top-bar" class="navbar-fixed-top animated-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- responsive nav button -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- /responsive nav button -->

      <!-- logo -->
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="images/logo.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- /logo -->
    </div>
    <!-- main menu -->
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
      <div class="main-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li> <a href="index.html">Hlavní strana</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="service.html">Service</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Služby <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="404.html">404 Page</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="blog-fullwidth.html">Blog Full</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="blog-left-sidebar.html">Blog Left sidebar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="blog-right-sidebar.html">Blog Right sidebar</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /main nav -->
  </div>
</header>
```

This is the file where I want insert Menu.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

<head>
  <!-- Basic Page Needs
        ================================================== -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
  <title>Internetové poradenství & služby</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Dan Caldr">
  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
        ================================================== -->
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Template CSS Files
        ================================================== -->
  <!-- Twitter Bootstrs CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons Fonts Css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- animate css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <!-- Hero area slider css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">
  <!-- owl craousel css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
  <!-- template main css file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <!-- responsive css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">

  <!-- Template Javascript Files
        ================================================== -->
  <!-- modernizr js -->
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- owl carouserl js -->
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap js -->

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- wow js -->
  <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
  <!-- slider js -->
  <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
  <!-- template main js -->
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <!-- Insert files THIS IS NOT WORKING-->
  <link rel="import" href="Menu.html">
</head>

<body>
  <!--
        ==================================================
        Slider Section Start
        ================================================== -->
  <section id="hero-area">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <div class="block wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">

            <!-- Slider -->
            <section class="cd-intro">
              <h1 class="wow fadeInUp animated cd-headline slide" data-wow-delay=".4s"> <span>Zajímáte se o</span><br>
              <span class="cd-words-wrapper"> <b class="is-visible">Získání více klientů?</b> <b>získání úspěchu na sociálních sítích?</b> <b>zefektivnění čiností?</b> <b> cokoliv jiného? </b> </span> </h1>
            </section>
            <!-- cd-intro -->
            <!-- /.slider -->
            <h2 class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".6s"> 
            <!-- Přidat něco o internetu--> "Internet je místo neuvěřitelných možností."<br>
            A rozhodně může výrazně pomct i vám.<br>
          </h2>
            <a class="btn-lines dark light wow fadeInUp animated smooth-scroll btn btn-default btn-green" data-wow-delay=".9s" href="#works" data-section="#works">nabídka</a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="block wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
            <h2> O mně </h2>
            <p>Díky několikaleté praxi jsem schopný pracovat s témněř jakýmkoliv programem. Vím jak fungují vyhledávače a jak Vás posunout nahoru. Umím perfektně zacházet se sociálními sítěmi.</p>
            <p>Vím, že univerzální řešení nemusí každému vyhovovat, a proto se snažím, aby moje služby byly efektivní a zároveň přátelské.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="block wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration="500ms">
            <img src="images/about/about.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/#main-slider-->
  <!--
            ==================================================
            Slider Section Start
            ================================================== -->
  <!-- /#about -->
  <!--
            ==================================================
            Portfolio Section Start
            ================================================== -->
  <section id="works" class="works">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-heading">
        <h1 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s">moje nabídka</h1>
        <p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">Soustředím se na tyto oblasti
          <br>Pokud potřebujete něco jiného můžete mě kontaktovat a já Vám zkusím připravit speciální řešení</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated portfolio-item" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="0ms">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
              <img src="images/portfolio/item-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title">
              <div class="overlay">
                <div class="buttons"> <a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="images/portfolio/item-1.jpg">Demo</a>  <a target="_blank" href="single-portfolio.html">Details</a> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <h4> <a href="#"> Pro podnikání </a> </h4>
              <p>Obchody, hotely, kadeřnictví...</p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
              <img src="images/portfolio/item-2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title">
              <div class="overlay">
                <div class="buttons"> <a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="images/portfolio/item-2.jpg">Demo</a>  <a target="_blank" href="single-portfolio.html">Details</a> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <h4> <a href="#"> Webové stránky </a> </h4>
              <p>Založení, přesun, nástroje, oprava...</p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <figure class="wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
              <img src="images/portfolio/item-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
              <div class="overlay">
                <div class="buttons"> <a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="images/portfolio/item-3.jpg">Demo</a>  <a target="_blank" href="single-portfolio.html">Details</a> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <h4> <a href="#"> Sociální sítě & další </a> </h4>
              <p>Youtube, Facebook... A jiné služby</p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- #works -->
  <!--
            ==================================================
            Portfolio Section Start
            ================================================== -->
  <section id="feature">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-heading">
        <h1 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s">Offer From Me</h1>
        <p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed,
          <br>quasi dolores numquam dolor vero ex, tempora commodi repellendus quod laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="media wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <div class="media-left">
              <div class="icon"> <i class="ion-ios-flask-outline"></i> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, sint.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
            <div class="media-left">
              <div class="icon"> <i class="ion-ios-lightbulb-outline"></i> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Well documented.</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, sint.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="900ms">
            <div class="media-left">
              <div class="icon"> <i class="ion-ios-lightbulb-outline"></i> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Well documented.</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, sint.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1200ms">
            <div class="media-left">
              <div class="icon"> <i class="ion-ios-americanfootball-outline"></i> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Free updates</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, sint.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1500ms">
            <div class="media-left">
              <div class="icon"> <i class="ion-ios-keypad-outline"></i> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Solid Support</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, sint.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1800ms">
            <div class="media-left">
              <div class="icon"> <i class="ion-ios-barcode-outline"></i> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Simple Installation</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, sint.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- /#feature -->
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just rename your file *.html to *.php

Comment: The files shall be located in the same folder -- or, you can add a path to the include file. What is the extension for the "master file", it needs the php extension (as in "myfile.php").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your main file to .php

Ex : if you have your file name index.html then rename it to index.php

Second step also rename your menu file to menu.php instead of menu.html

then you can do like this

in index file:

```
<html>
    Your html code here
    <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
</html>
```

Always remember that if you want to include files in PHP they should have a .php extension

Also remember that the file in which you are including should also have a .php extension

Ex : if you are including menu.php in index.html then it wont work

Comment: please vote the answer as useful :)